# Removing an ubuntu package with chef

Tags: ubuntu, apt, chef

An older version of a cookbook installed a package that I no longer want on my systems.  My understanding is that chef doesn't have a straightforward way to explicitly remove a package, so I resorted to the blunt hammer of `execute`:

```
execute "Remove nasty perl gearman-server" do
    command "apt-get -y remove gearman-server"
    ignore_failure true
end
```

But this fails, I'm guessing because chef itself has the lock on dpkg?

```
STDERR: E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

How can I programmatically ensure that this package is no longer on my machines?  If it's not clear, I'm totally happy with an ubuntu-only solution.

Comment: That error indicates some other package tool was already running.  Were doing something in another window/terminal?  I don't know chef, but I find it difficult to believe that it create that lock.

Comment: Agreed.  The lock must have been taken by another dpkg or apt process, possibly another chef-client also.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Chef [package resource](http://docs.opscode.com/resource_package.html) allows removal or purging of packages in a distro independent manner:

```
package "gearman-server" do
  action :remove
end
```

This code will remove the package if it is installed, or do nothing if the package is not.